# Clear in scala (call cls in scala program running in cmd )

Tags: windows, scala, cls

In python this works:

```
 clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
 clear()
```

How would I do that in scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `print("\u001b[2J")`?

Comment: Nice! Or `print("\u001b[2J"); print("\u001b[H")` seems to have the same behavior as `"clear.!` mentioned above (clear console and move to the top left).

Answer (score 6):

For REPL there is :keybindings, Ctrl + L clears the screen.

Answer (score 5):

Using REPL started from a bash shell:

```scala
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> def clear() = "clear".!
clear: ()Int

scala> clear()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work using REPL stated from cmd window in windows though.

Answer (score 0):

use this code.
`print("\033c")` this removes all charset

it will clear away everything in the Scala REPL.